# PHP - change first folder in url but keep remaining folders as is

Tags: php

using if else statement, I would like php to check if the first folder in the url is (en),
example:
http://www.domain.com/en/newyork/car/
if the first folder is [ en ] as shown above in the example, then I would like to change the ahref of a link that I have on the page

change link from:
En

change link to:
Ru

Looking at the example above, the only thing I want php to change is en or ru but keeps the remaining url of the current page as is

: if the current page url is http://www.domain.com/en/newyork/car/
the link would be Russian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the current language of your page, you will first have to get the *path* of your current URL, and then get the string after the first slash. You could do this as follows:

```
// Get the current URL
$current_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

// Get the 'path' portion (without things like 'http')
$url = parse_url($current_url);

// Split the String in an array
$parts = explode('/', $url['path']);
$lang = $parts[1];
$prepath = $url['scheme'] . '://' . $url['host'] . $parts[0];

// Array slice to get all remaining parts
$postpath = array_slice($parts, 2);

// Append the first part of your path, the new language, and finally 
// the remainder of your URL.
$newurl = $prepath . '/' . ($lang == 'ru'?'':'ru/') . implode('/', $postpath);
```

After this, you can use an anchor on your page to allow the user to change:

```
<a href="<?php echo $newurl;?>">Change Language</a>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply,, this is in the essence what am looking for, but it is not working

Comment: this is the nest answer but I do not know why it is not working

Comment: What issue are you getting? An error, or incorrect output?

Comment: thanks Erik, working on localhost,, the page doesnot load due to php error

Comment: Working,,,,, the reason the above was not working was that there were missing (;) after $lang and $prepath

Comment: what if the english language does not have its own folder; meaning the english version resides at the url: www.example.com/newyork/car/ then the how can I have the new URL for russian version be: www.example.com/ru/newyork/car

Comment: In that case, simply change the ternary from `($lang == 'en'?'ru':'en')` to `($lang == 'ru'?'':'ru/')`. That way, if that part of the URL is `ru`, it will switch to an URL without the language part.

Comment: Hello Erik, thanks it work but it does not show the remaining folders after the ru language;
meaning if my url is example.com/newyork, using your code it give me example.com/ru/ without the folder newyork

Comment: [Click here](http://goo.gl/zDWcsu) for a working demonstration. I've had to edit a few parts to make it work; Most notably, the `$prepath` and `$postpath`. Because you wanted to leave out the language for english, while `$postpath` still assumed that index 1 always held a language, the first part after that language would be left out. I'll also update my answer to reflect the changes.

Comment: Thank you Erik, am kind of novice to php, i tried your example but with no luck as it assumes, if I understand right, that i only want to change the url from example.com/newyork/car to example.com/ru/newyork/car, but actually i wanted the function to change the current URL whatever that maybe to: adding always ru as the second folder in the new url

example.com/denver/car
example.com/ru/denver/car

Comment: Erik, i think i have successfully solved the issue residing back with your old code; all i had to change was:
$postpath = array_slice($parts, 1) which i change from 2 to 1
and
($lang == ''?'':'ru')

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$url = 'www.domain.com/en/newyork/car/';
$url_arr = explode("/en/", $url);
$new_url = implode("/ru/", $url_arr);
?>
```

Comment: Nice, elegant solution to replace that part of the URL :)

Comment: this is not what am looking for; am looking for what Erik has provided but unfortunately its not working

Answer (score 0):

```
function changeUrlComponent($url, $componentPos, $newVal) {
    $url = parse_url($url);
    $arr = explode('/',$url['path']);
    $arr[$componentPos] = $newVal;
    $url['path'] = implode('/',$arr);
    return $url['scheme'] .'://'. $url['host'] . $url['path'];
}

echo changeUrlComponent('http://www.domain.com/en/newyork/car/', 1, 'ru');
```

Hope this helps. Also note you can add more to the returned value based on the expected no of url components. Refer to [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php). Also the componentPos should start from 1 to length of your directories/path. This would be a more generic approach than the ones answered above as they are too coupled with the expectation of a lang being present in the url.

Comment: The function is associated with the header which will be loaded with many different pages;;; the above is associated with http://www.domain.com/en/newyork/car/

Comment: What header are you talking about? I could not understand your comment

Comment: If I do understand your comment, you can simply put the function in a file which you can include on each page. Having one function on many pages is no problem, if it is used on all/most of them.

Comment: I still dint get it. Haha I'm sorry. No need to explain me more. My job is done here.